# How does a service identify the user?

Tags: google-mirror-api

## Use case:

A user takes a beautiful photo and wants to save it to their evernote account.

[image]

1. User authorizes with OAuth 2.0. The service stores their credentials.
2. Just after the OAuth 2.0 dance completes, the service inserts a contact called "Save to Evernote".
3. Next, the service subscribes to updates in this user's timeline by inserting a subscription for the timeline collection.
4. The user activates the contact. Save to Evernote is now fully set up.
5. Over time, the user takes photos.
6. The user shares a photo with Save to Evernote. This makes the timeline card associated with this photo accessible to the service.
7. Because the service is subscribed to timeline updates, a notification is sent to your service. This notification links to the timeline item containing the shared photo.
8. The service examines the notification and uses the included id to fetch the timeline card that contains the photo.
9. Next, the service examines the timeline item and uses the attachment ID to fetch the bytes of the photo.
10. The service uploads the photo to the user's Evernote.
11. Finally, the service constructs a new timeline card and inserts it into the user's timeline card with the success message.

From the [Mirror API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/subscriptions#shared_picture) it appears that once a user shares a timeline item the service receives a POST quite like this:

```
{
  "collection": "timeline",
  "itemId": "3hidvm0xez6r8_dacdb3103b8b604_h8rpllg",
  "operation": "UPDATE",
  "userToken": "harold_penguin",
  "verifyToken": "random_hash_to_verify_referer",
  "userActions": [
    {
      "type": "SHARE"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is the userToken a value that I receive when first authenticating the application? If so can I use that value to connect the POST received from Glass with the User saved in my database? If not how do I connect the share to my service's contact with the Glass user so that my service can perform services specific to that user on their behalf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `userToken` is indeed the field you use to correlate the notification back to the user who triggered it.

You set the `userToken` when you create a [subscription](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/subscriptions#userToken) for that user. Whatever value you specify when you insert the subscription is provided as the `userToken` for all of the notifications that it yields. This means that when you create subscriptions, you always want to use unique identifiers that your system can correlate back to the correct user.

For example:

1. Jane authenticates with your service. Jane has the unique user ID of 42 in your Glassware's database.
2. At the time of authentication, you subscribe to her `timeline` collection by inserting this subscription:

   ```
   {
     "collection": "timeline"
     "userToken": "42",
     "callbackUrl": "https://example.com/notify/callback"
   }
   ```
3. Jane shares a photo with your Glassware.
4. A notification is sent to your service. It looks something like this:

   ```
   {
     "collection": "timeline",
     "itemId": "3hidvm0xez6r8_dacdb3103b8b604_h8rpllg",
     "operation": "UPDATE",
     "userToken": "42",
     "userActions": [
       {
         "type": "SHARE"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
5. Your Glassware uses the `userToken` property to look up the correct user: Jane.

The rest of the story proceeds as you describe in your question.

Comment: Aha! This is very helpful. Thank you for the clarification. I cannot wait to build more apps. I have a few that I have prototyped that I am waiting to take to the next level.

Comment: When a user shares with **anyone** wouldn't my Glassware get a notification since it is simply a hook on timeline updates? If so would my Glassware need to send a get request to each one to check the recipients array of the timeline item to see if it includes my Glassware contact?

Comment: @DrewBaumann from reading https://developers.google.com/glass/subscriptions looks like you only get notifications on your app's timeline items or location changes

Comment: Okay I wrote my code in a way that should be a moot point. Regardless it would be good to get official word. I imagine @monica is correct though.

Comment: @DrewBaumann: Monica is correct. You only receive a notification about timeline updates for cards that you have access to. This is mostly cards you inserted, and also cards that were created by sharing with your contact.